Get all record source details for all forms in Access DB
I am in the process of splitting an Access database to move the data to a SQL Server. Application testing has found a form not loading due to the query syntax that supports the forms referencing Access tables not being compatible TSQL now the data is in the SQL database. I have resolved this one case but would like to iterate through all forms and where they have a query record source, review the query syntax for possible issues.
How do I get the record source for all Forms please?
So far I can use FOREACH to get all form names (below) but the form object doesn't appear to have a RecordSource property.
Public Sub AllFormsList()
  Dim frm As AccessObject, db As Object
  Set db = Application.CurrentProject

  For Each frm In db.AllForms
    ' this lists all form names as expected
    Debug.Print frm.Name
    
    'but there is no RecordSource property ??
    frm.Recordsource
  Next frm
End Sub

I can see that I will need to do the same thing on the Queries collection as the problematic form had a Query record source and the query needed the syntax change so any bonus guidance on that future problem too would be much appreciated.

A form can be unbound, or the RecordSource may be set from code when running the application.

AllForms gets you only a list of names. To retrieve any properties you need to open them - see linked duplicate.

The forms and their data source, and that of including their query source should NOT be changed, and when using the Access to SQL server migration wizard, I VERY STRONG recommend you don't attempt to migrate the queries. So, client side queries can continue to use forms!expressions, but that is the case as long as you do NOT attempt to migrate the Access client side queries - leave them "as is", and don't try to migrate the Access queries when using SSMAA tools to migrate the table data.  Migrate ONLY the tables using that tool. While it can try + attempt to migrate the queries, I suggest not
